# Import error for Django and GAE on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows, google-app-engine, importerror

I'm trying to run Django + GAE app , but I got an import error:

```
File "C:\Users\abatutin\Downloads\chapter10\chapter10\webapp-chapter10-simpleform\webapp-chapter10-simpleform\simpleform.py", line 7, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext.db import djangoforms
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\djangoforms.py", line 97, in <module>
import django.core.exceptions
```

ImportError: No module named django.core.exceptions

Python 2.7
Django 1.5.1 - goes with GAE distribution for Windows.

Any ideas?

yaml file

```
application: simpleform
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /*.
  script: simpleform.py
```

Comment: How have you configured django in the libraries section of app.yaml

Comment: see description for the yaml file

Comment: In other words, you haven't.  You need to configure libraries in app.yaml to include the django env.  Please read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

Comment: app.yaml file seems ok, if you need can add `libraries:
- name: django
  version: latest` in the end of the file, also can **copy the django folder to you apps root directory**